# Creating animation from multi-band raster?

Tags: raster, geotiff-tiff, animation

I have a GeoTiff raster with 1461 bands, each band representing 1 day for a total of 4 years. Basically, the geotiff is just a collection of 1461 images.

What would be the best option to animate this GeoTiff that shows all bands in succession? 
Ideally I want to show 24 bands (24 frames sequentially) per second in my video/gif.

Comment: Is this what you are after?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35943809/1446289

Comment: GRASS GIS offers some nice tools here: https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/WxGUI_Animation_Tool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of a roundabout method, but here's what worked for me:

- Make a shell script w/ gdal_translate to extract all bands as
  separate .tif files

  `gdal_translate -b <bandnum> in.tif out<bandnum>.tif`
- (Optional) For my case I needed to apply a custom colormap to each .tif file, so I used MultiQML + Qgis console. Output:`colored<bandnum>.tif`
- Another shell script w/ gdal_translate to convert the .tif files to .jpg

  `gdal_translate -of JPEG -co worldfile=yes colored<bandnum>.tif out<bandnum>.jpg`
- Finally, imageio to make .gif from .jpg files (fps=24). Taken from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35943809/10466005).